# Modifying an irregular length bit field in a register in C/C++

Tags: c, programming

Suppose I wanted to modify the field ADD[7:0] in the following register:

[image]

I wrote this to make things more convenient.

```
  {
    const uint8_t Character = USART_TERMINATION_CHAR; //8-bit ASCII termination character
    
    //masks to modify register
    uint32_t Zero_Mask = ~Character;
    uint32_t One_Mask = Character;
    
    //shift so mask will apply to appropriate location in "CR2" register
    Zero_Mask = Zero_Mask << 24;
    One_Mask = One_Mask << 24;
    
    MODIFY_REG(USART1->CR2, Zero_Mask, One_Mask); //USART_CR_ADD[7:0], address or character match symbol
  }
```

But if the field, in question, was an irregular number of bits, for example DIVR[6:0]:

[image]

How would I actually do this? Because in the code snippet above I was relying on the uint8_t type being the same length as the field. But there exists no 7-bit data type and if I use something like uint8_t the mask is going to be modifying bits outside of the field due to the presence of extraneous bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the new value to make a mask. Instead you simply need to clear all bits in the region you care about, and then the set mask is the new value.

For example, for `DIVR1`, you would do:

```
MODIFY_REG(<reg>,0x7F<<24,(newVal & 0x7F)<<24);
```

To understand this further, lets split it up into what's going on. Under the assumption you are using an STM32 type processor (just a guess), the [`MODIFY_REG`](http://stm32.kosyak.info/doc/group___exported__macro.html) macro expands to:

```
WRITE_REG((REG), (((READ_REG(REG)) & (~(CLEARMASK))) | (SETMASK)))
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
uint32_t tempVal = REG; //Read the register value
tempVal &= ~CLEARMASK;  //Clear all bits that are set to 1 in the mask
tempVal |= SETMASK;     //Set the new bits
REG = tempVal;          //Assign the value back
```

The clearing step basically will take any bit set to a 1 in the `CLEARMASK`, and set the corresponding bit in the temporary value to 0. It doesn't matter if one of those bits is already zero.

With all the bits in your register chunk clear, then the `SETMASK` becomes simply your value to set the chunk to. Any bits that are 1 in the mask will be set as expected, any bits that are 0 will already be zero in the temporary value as you've already cleared them.

So the first example expands to:

```
uint32_t temp = <reg>;
temp &= ~(0x7F << 24); //Clear bits 30:24 inclusive (0x7F is a value of seven consecutive ones)
temp |= ((newVal & 0x7F) << 24); //Sets the new value into bits 30:24.
<reg> = temp;
```

Note that we mask the new value to ensure that any bits beyond the seven we are interested in are not accidentally affected. You could also do:

```
uint32_t mask = 0x7F << 24;
MODIFY_REG(<reg>,mask,(data << 24) & mask);
```

Which would be equivalent.

Comment: So in other words, I can clear the entire field manually to make sure I don't step out of bounds, and just mask in the 1s of the new value. And as long as I enter in a valid new value it won't set the extraneous bits since they should be zeroes in my new value anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't rocket science, but everyday embedded programming... some basic rules:

- never write register access (or anything else for that matter) using "magic numbers". Always used named constants.
- prefix all named constants with the register name so that the reader knows which register they belong to.
- all integer constants in C have a type and it is most often `int` which is signed and therefore unsuitable for bitwise arithmetic. Therefore we must `u` suffix all constants in embedded programming, particularly those used for bitwise arithmetic.

With these rules in place we end up with something like this:

```
#define REG_DIVR1_POS 24u  // where "REG" should be replaced by the name of the register.
#define REG_DIVR1_MASK 0x7Fu

REG = (val & REG_DIVR1_MASK) << REG_DIVR1_POS;
```

Alternatively:

```
#define REG_DIVR1_POS 24u
#define REG_DIVR1_MASK 0x7F000000u

REG = (val << REG_DIVR1_POS) & REG_DIVR1_MASK;
```

Various bloatware such as STM HAL or Atmel ASF are deadly afraid of hardware in general and registers in particular, so they tend to hide the above "scary" code behind a function-like macro, along the lines of this:

```
#define REG_DIVR1(x) ( ((x) & REG_DIVR1_MASK) << REG_RIVR1_POS )
```

Macros like this are turning rather common because of bloatware libs, but this macro doesn't actually add anything. In particular, it does *not* improve readability. Do not write them, do not write bloated function wrappers either. As a C programmer you are *expected* to be perfectly capable of understanding the line `REG = (val << REG_DIVR1_POS) & REG_DIVR1_MASK;` as it is among the most readable code you can encounter. If you don't understand it, then you need more C training, not more bloatware function wrappers.

Also see: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: The 24 is a magic number in this case because I was not about to go into the CMSIS register definitions add add one in. It is also only used locally with the curly brackets. The thing above is not a function wrapper. It just has curly brackets to force the declared variables there to be local and unaccessible elsewhere. I find can read that line but I do find the "MODIFY_REG" does increase readability when I have hundreds of them in a list and need to scan through it.

Comment: @DKNguyen You should only write to each register one single time, or in some special cases a few times in sequence. So if you have hundreds of lines writing to registers in a list, something is very strange with your program design. Each hardware peripheral should have its register setup inside its own driver, and even for the more complex ones you rarely ever need to set more than 20 registers or so.

Comment: Indeed the MODIFY_REG macro is not used often. The SET_BIT and CLEAR_BIT macros which are not used in the example are the ones that exist by the hundreds and MODIFY_REG is only used when a field (as opposed to a bit) needs to be written to. It helps me segment the different configurations for re-use without constantly referring to the datasheet  and scan the list.

Comment: I will probably change the supplied modify_reg macro though since it is really ackward to always need a two masks

Comment: Your post also made me go back and look at the register definitions provided for the original project this code came from. The register definitions for are quite ackward in that no bit positions are provided. I think that is why the MODIFY_REG macro needs the double mask. Without bit positions it is impossible to write to a field without magic numbers. Instead, they provide a mask for each bit (no masks provided for fields). Luckily the new MCU for the new project provides both bit positions for shifts and masks for entire fields.

Comment: So finally I can write to an n-bit field in one operation instead of flipping n-bits individually.